# pyAssimp opengl - generating normals

Tags: python, opengl

After loading `.obj` file with postprocess argument `'aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_Fast'` my mesh normals aren't calculated from bump map - normals arrays are just empty. I tried also to use full path and path with dot in my `.mtl` file, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to load normals or do I have to do it myself?

Of course I wanted also to get Tangent space, but without normals eh. 
I don't have normal vectors in obj, but only bump map.

Comment: Why would mesh normals be calculated from a *bump map*? That's not what the [OAI documentation](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/postprocess_8h.html) says the flag does; it generates face normals, which would give a faceted appearance. Also, how did you manage to get a bump map on a mesh with no normals?

Comment: oh, I didn't notice, I just thought this feature was included in this argument